# How to tell when a user is logged in | Express | Passport | Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I've built myself an express back-end API (Port 3000) and a Vue.js front end on port (8080) I've implemented a passport authentication login system on my back-end server. If i go to localhost:3000/auth/google the login system works and I get a google-ID in my mongoose database.

I have this code on my server which redirects to my front end on successful login, but how do i now know a user is logged in on my Vue.js front-end?

```
app.get(
  '/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['profile']
  })
);

app.get(
  '/auth/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('http://localhost:8080/profile');
  }
);
```

and my passport config is set up like so

`````
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

module.exports = function(passport, GoogleStrategy) {
  passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
      {
        clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback'
      },
      function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
        var query = { googleId: profile.id };
        var update = {
          $set: {
            googleId: profile.id
          }
        };
        var options = { new: true, upsert: true };
        User.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function(err, u) {
          return done(err, u);
        });
      }
    )
  );
};````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a `jsonwebtoken` and set it in the cookie of the `response` object

```
app.get(
  '/auth/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    let token = jwt.sign({
       exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 60),
       user: req.user //if you have user here
       }, 'secret');
    res.cookie("token", token, {httpOnly:false})
    res.redirect('http://localhost:8080/profile');
  }
);
```

and in Vue you can use a package like `vue-cookies` to get the cookie `$cookies.get('token')`

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I needed. I've received it but how do I decrypt it? 
````this.data = this.$cookies.get('token');
      var decoded = jwt.verify(this.data, '18331831');;````
Isnt working?

Comment: decode it in the backend in a middleware function for example

Answer (score 0):

Inside your protected route, you should be able to see the User in the req.user field:

```
app.get('/protectedURL',
  passport.authenticate('google'),
  function(req, res) {
    res.json(req.user);
  });
```

The call to /protectedURL will return a 401 error if the user is not logged in.

Comment: But how do i do that from my front end? I have to redirect to a different port? I think im missing something..

Comment: Why are you redirecting to a different port? If it's going to a different server, then that server needs to use the same passport setup and connect to the same session information. The user information is stored in the session and you need the same passport setup to be able to deserialize the user from the session.

Comment: Because I Vue automatically started it on 8080 i didn't think much of it. If i make it the same port will it be easier?

Comment: Look at using a [dev server proxy](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy) in Vue, so your front/back end don't need to know they are separate servers: 
  `module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'http://localhost:4000'
  }
}
`